# How to setup an react-native environment in windows 10 with hyper-v enabled

Tags: android, react-native

how can I set up an environment for developing an react-native app under windows 10 with hyper-v enabled?
I need to keep hyper-v active due to running docker at the same time.
I will post my answer below showing which software I chose to make this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all us who need to develop under windows 10, a setup for developing a react-app can be challenging. I am posting here the steps to make sure the most common mistakes are taken care of (and I remember all the steps).

1. You need nodejs - https://nodejs.org/en/ (basic install)
2. You need android studio (yes you can go the SDK only way, I used basic install). I have choosen to install all sdk in a specific folder (x:/androidsk)
3. You need Java SDK. I tried with 1.9 and failed. And failed. **Try 1.8** for now and how everything else will get fixed in the future.
4. Since the internal android studio (and any other emulator i found) requires you to shut down the hyper-v -> I am using the brilliant visual emulator from visual studio https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/
5. Since you are using the visual emulator - please follow http://blog.tpcware.com/2017/03/visual-studio-2017-android-emulation/ to enable external data access
6. Download and install a visual emulator profile -> Make sure it is **above 5.x** other wise you can **not use the adb reverse**!
7. You will need to configure a couple of environment variables:
8. ANDROID_HOME -> where your SDK are (x:/androidsk) **READ NEXT STEPS!**
9. While assuming that this enables all of the features - I needed to additionally add the following two paths to allow me to reverse the port with ADB --> (x:/androidsk/tools) + (x:/androidsk/plattform-tools)
10. react-native --> run `npm install -g react-native-cli` in your shell, no magic here.

Comment: In step 6, what is the visual emulator profile and where would I download it from?

Comment: Hey, you can add the profiles from within the emulator, there is a little download button. On the left it states the screen size and OS (go for something higher than 5)

Comment: For those hunting for a vm solution. Running android emulator hyper-v acceleration inside a vm is not yet supported. You can upvote the feature here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/719225/vs-android-emulator-hyper-v-support-inside-a-vm.html